# getting values of the clicked row and assigning cell's values to corresponding inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with id="selector".

Each row's cell has a corresponding input to it.

```
<td class="cell1"><b>Cell 1</b></td>

<input type="text" name="cell1" id="cell1">
```

What I need to do is to capture the whole row and assign certain cells to the inputs (not all cells will be assigned to inputs). In this example it would just be cell1.

```
<script type="text/javascript ">
   $('#selector tr').click(function() {  
    var values = ($(this).html()); // this is the whole row

    // no idea what to do now
   $("#cell1").val($(this)) // don't know how to select cell1

            });
</script>
```

EDIT: #sub1 -> #cell1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to "capture the whole row" via `html()`.

```
$('#selector tr').click(function() {  
  $("#sub1").val( $(this).find("td").get(0).text() );
});
```